# Avro aliases inside Union type throwing Unknown union branch

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I am working with a the following schema.

```
{"fields":[{"default":null,"name":"corelationId","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"eventId","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"eventTime","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"eventType","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"resourceOrders","aliases":["resourceOrder"],"type":["null",{"fields":[{"default":null,"name":"expectedCompletionDate","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"resourceOrderItem","type":["null",{"items":{"fields":[{"default":null,"name":"errorMessage","type":["null",{"items":{"fields":[{"default":null,"name":"additionalInfoCode","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"additionalInfoCorrectionValue","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"additionalInfoMessage","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"code","type":["null","string"]},{"default":null,"name":"message","type":["null","string"]}],"name":"item","aliases":["items"],"namespace":"properties.resourceOrders.properties.resourceOrderItem.items.properties.errorMessage","type":"record"},"type":"array"}]}],"name":"item","aliases":["items"],"namespace":"properties.resourceOrders.properties.resourceOrderItem","type":"record"},"type":"array"}]}],"name":"resourceOrders","aliases":["resourceOrder"],"namespace":"properties","type":"record"}]},{"default":null,"name":"sourceSystem","type":["null","string"]}],"name":"NotifyExportResponseAvro","namespace":"xxx.yyy.zzz","type":"record"}
```

I am trying to validate following payload

```
{"corelationId":{"string":"cxd-abc"},"eventId":{"string":"1231250602"},"eventTime":{"string":"2022-09-27 09:18:24.495"},"eventType":{"string":"ResourceOrderExportResponseEvent"},"resourceOrder":{"properties.resourceOrder":{"expectedCompletionDate":{"string":"2022-10-12"},"resourceOrderItem":null}},"sourceSystem":{"string":"zzz"}}
```

The command I am using

```
java -jar ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/avro/avro-tools/1.11.2/avro-tools-1.11.2.jar  fromjson --schema-file some.avsc  data-basic.json
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch properties.resourceOrder                                                                     at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readIndex(JsonDecoder.java:434)                                                                                                       at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readIndex(ResolvingDecoder.java:282)                                                                                             at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:188)                                                                        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)                                                                                         at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:260)                                                                                    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:248)                                                                                   at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:180)                                                                        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:161)                                                                                         at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:154)                                                                                         at org.apache.avro.tool.DataFileWriteTool.run(DataFileWriteTool.java:89)                                                                                                at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.run(Main.java:67)                                                                                                                          at org.apache.avro.tool.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

However when I change the data to the following the payload is getting validated.. Though I've used `resourceOrder` as an `aliases`

```
...
  "resourceOrder": {
    "properties.resourceOrders": {
      "expectedCompletionDate": {
        "string": "2022-10-12"
      },
      "resourceOrderItem": null
    }
  },
...
```

Question is why avro-tool is accepting aliases inside an union? Is this bug in the tool or this valid behavior?
How can I change the schema as I can get both `resourceOrder` and `resourceOrders`?